# Group chat database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables for different types of users..

```
Admin - Admin_id, Admin_name
User - User_id, User_Name
Employer - Emp_Id, Emp_Name..
```

Now I want to have group chat database design between all of them.
How can I fetch message from the following : 
In 1 group there can be only 1 user, 1 employer and 1 Admin

Currently I have 1 to 1 chat design, which is as follows:

```
Id, message, from_user, to_user, from_usertype, to_usertype, datetime
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a design like this:

```
tblChats
--------
ChatId 
AdminId 
UserId 
EmployerId 

tblMessages
-----------
MessageId 
ChatId 
From (enum - admin/user/employer)
To (enum - admin/user/employer)
Content 
DateSent
```

Comment: but actually i have 3 different types of user in different table.. so how can we consider From and To field in tblMessages table ?.. imagine that user has messaged for particular group... so with this database design how can we store and retrieve same message at user, employer and admin side  ?

Comment: The tblMessages relates to the tblChats. in the tblChats you have the admin id, user id and employer id, so in the tblMessages all you need to save a value that indicates to which of these columns the message relates to in both From an To columns. No need to save the message for every user, you just save it once.